# MVC Error Handling - log the original URL into the website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-headers

In my website I am using CustomErrors to send the user to my Error Controller when an exception is thrown.

```
<customErrors mode="On"  defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage/DisplayError/500" >
    <error redirect="~/ErrorPage/DisplayError/500" statusCode="500" />
```

In my error controller I can get the Url of the page where the error has taken place.

```
this.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

which might return http://wwww.mysite.com/page5

however I want to get the original Url, which might be http://wwww.mysite.com/page1

The reason for this is that we have seen a spike in hits to the ErrorController's 500 page since we began working with a third party. Links on the third party's site have parameters. We therefore want to get the original Url when the ErrorController is hit to see if the user came via that website.

http://wwww.mysite.com/page1?p=abc123

Is this possible using server side code rather than dropping a cookie onto the browser and reading it if the page is hit?

Comment: Well, this is two years old now, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I would recommend using a cookie to track the user's journey throughout the website. This is the best solution to the problem.

Comment: Great thanks! I'll check that out.